# What do I do after backing up my data (with Deja Dup)?

Tags: backup, restore

I know it may sound a bit hilarious,but what should I do with a backed up system in case I want to restore it?
Can I store the files on an USB or optical disk and then simply reinstall my system..?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I store the files on an USB or optical disk and then simply reinstall my system..?

Yes. Things to consider: Duplicity will not overwrite an existing file. Encryption.

Command line restore according to the man page:

```
duplicity [restore] [options] [--file-to-restore <relpath>] 
[--time time] source_url target_directory
```

Example (adding encryption; skip that if you did not use it):

```
export PASSPHRASE=SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey
duplicity restore {--no-encryption} --file-to-restore single.txt "file:///media/{mountpoint}/" "/home/{username}/"
unset PASSPHRASE
```

where {no-encryption} if no encryption, single.txt can be wildcards, {mountpoint} points to your external disk, and {username} your user name.

Mind that you will need the passphrase if you used encryption and can not retrieve it if you forget it. Besides that: always test if you can restore it BEFORE deleting you current OS. It might even be worth it extracting the last backup onto the external media and use that to restore your personal files (that way you know you have the files that you want).

Comment: And...how do I test it?Do I have to uninstall my actual system? Sorry if it sounds stupid =) but I want to make sure I don't make any mistake.

Comment: You can always extract a single file. But if I was you I would extract the personal data and settings (aka. /home/$USER) to the external disk (if there is enough room there) so you have the files extracted om the external media. That makes it 100% sure you can copy them over to your system.